Side panel button on chrome is gone?
Anyone is using chrome? I've fonud out recently that the side panel is gone which was located on top-right corner before on Chorme. Is this a bug or should I need some settings? This is how my menu bar look.


did you solve this issue?I also encountered the same problem.

CN.hitori gives me a good solution.

Relative links: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/268819997/missing-side-panel-icon-for-chrome?hl=en-gb, https://9to5google.com/2024/04/12/chrome-side-panel-button/

I found the sulotion,you can disable "Side panel navigation and pinning updates" this feature in chrome://flags/#enable-tab-grid-layout

